# find day of given data (in text: eg February 8, 2019)

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, data-analysis

I know there are similar questions but most of them seem to refer to cases when we enter date in a numerical format eg: 01-12-2020. But what if we have a date in this format: February 8, 2019

How can we find the correct day for it?

I tried using this:

```
date=str(input('February 1, 2020:'))
day_name= ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday']
day = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d %Y').weekday()
print(day_name[day])
```

but the format doesn't match, probably because of the comma.

Comment: "*probably because of the comma*" - well, why don't you add it? `.strptime('February 1, 2020:', '%B %d, %Y:')`

Comment: btw. you can use `.strftime('%A')` to get the weekday's name.

Comment: Could you give an example of its usage? @MrFuppes ```.strftime('%A')```

Comment: @urban already has this in his answer.

Comment: a good format directives ressource: https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `strptime` where you can specify the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) your date is in and convert it to python date/time object from it. The reverse can be done with `strftime` which given a date, converts it to a string based on the given format. Combining these two you can do:

```
import datetime

date_time_str = 'February 8, 2019'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%B %d, %Y')

# UPDATE
print(date_time_obj)
print(date_time_obj.strftime("%A"))
```

Gives you:

```
$ python3 ./so.py 
2019-02-08 00:00:00
Friday
```